# Change value of <input> to include a superscript, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, superscript

The following code works correctly for me, in HTML.

```
<input type = "text"   name = "var_1"   id = "i_var_1"   value = "x&sup8">
```

The following, using Javascript, also works:

```
<p id = "p1"><input type = "text"   name = "var_1"   id = "i_var_1"   value = "0"></p>

<script....>

q1 = document.getElementById("p1");

q1.innerHTML = '<INPUT TYPE = "text"   name = "var_1a"   id = "i_var_1a"  value = "x&sup8">';

</script>
```

However I need to add in the superscript when a button is pressed. So I have something like:

```
<p id = "p1"><input type = "text"   name = "var_1"   id = "i_var_1"   value = "0"></p>

<input type = "button"   id = "i_button"   value = "Add the superscript"    onclick="Add_Superscript()";>

<script.....>

function Add_Superscript()
{

q1 = document.getElementById("p1");

b1 = document.getElementById("i_var_1");

c1 = b1.value.toString() + "&sup8";

q1.innerHTML = '<INPUT TYPE = "text"   name = "var_1a"   id = "i_var_1a"  value = c1.value>';

}

</script>
```

The above code does not reproduce the superscript properly.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks in advance for comments.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by superscript. There is a superscript tag in HTML, but I'm not sure that's what you want: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup

Comment: @Richard.Davenport—please don't reference w3schools, the site is full of errors. Consider MDN or the relevant standard instead.

Comment: @RobG I guess there are better websites out there with fewer errors regarding the sup tag. Your comment has breathed new meaning into my life and I am eternally grateful! I will now carry the burden of commenting on any helpful post that mentions such a terrible website. Hopefully we can spread the news of such a bad resource and prevent other helpless souls. How can I ever repay you for your wisdom and guidance? Have you submitted your errors to them? With links to the correct,  more perfect resources? If not you should totally waste your time doing that too along with your comments on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but it adds &sup8 to whatever is in the input box.

```js
function Add_Superscript() {

  q1 = document.getElementById("p1");

  b1 = document.getElementById("i_var_1");
  
  c1 = b1.value.toString() + "&sup8";

  q1.innerHTML = '<INPUT TYPE = "text"   name = "var_1a"   id = "i_var_1a"  value = "' + c1 + '">';

}
```

```html
<p id="p1">
  <input type="text" name="var_1" id="i_var_1" value="0">
</p>

<input type="button" id="i_button" value="Add the superscript" onclick="Add_Superscript()" ;>
```

Comment: This code throws an error if you click the button a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You have several typos in your code and a lot of unnecessary code as well.  You just need to set up a click event handler on the button that populates the `value` of the pre-existing `input`. No need to create a new `input`.

A few notes:

When you were trying to create the new `input` element (which it turns out you don't need to do in the first place), you had the entire thing as a string. You need to inject the dynamic value into that string, by terminating the string, concatenating the new value in and then concatenating the closing of the string, like this:

```
q1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="var_1a" id="i_var_1a" value=' + c1.value + '>';
```

Next, it's best to use good naming conventions for elements and variables. Prefix an `id` and `name` with something that describes the "type" of thing the element is. Use `btn` (button), `txt` (textbox), `chk` (checkbox), `rad` (radio button), etc. And don't use `_` (that's a very old convention). Instead use "camelCase". Further, with form elements, you need to give them a `name` for form submission purposes, but it is also a good idea to give them and `id` for CSS and JavaScript purposes. Use the same `id` that you used for `name` so that you don't have two different names for the same thing.

Lastly, don't configure your HTML elements to event handlers via HTML attributes (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.). Doing this creates global anonymous functions that alter the `this` binding in the callback function, it creates "spaghetti code" that is hard to scale and debug and it doesn't follow the **[W3C DOM Event specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)**. Instead, do all the work in JavaScript and use `.addEventListener()` to connect functions to events.

```js
// Get references to the relevant DOM elements
var btn = document.getElementById("btnGo");
var input = document.getElementById("txtInput");

// Set up a click event handling function
btn.addEventListener("click", add_Superscript);

function add_Superscript(){
 // Create a new value that is the old value plus a "superscript" value
 var newVal = input.value + "&sup8";
 // Update the input with the new value:
 input.value = newVal;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" value="0">
</p>

<input type = "button" id="btnGo" value="Add the superscript">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do but maybe it's because of the c1.value ! Try:
`q1.innerHTML = '<INPUT TYPE = "text"   name = "var_1a"   id = "i_var_1a"  value =' + c1 + '>';`